# C#: Why does the following comparison indicate that 0 != 0

Tags: c#, reflection, equality, autoboxing

I've stumbled across in interesting bug in some comparison code recently where two objects both have a property equal to 0.0m. When that property is converted to an int and compared, the comparison is never equal. Reproduction below:

Take an abstraction A, and two implementations, B and C:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public decimal MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
}

public class C : A
{
}
```

The abstraction defines several public properties, primarily, but not entirely, decimal. All public properties are always primitives. The concrete subtypes represent this abstraction as obtained from two different data sources. Two objects of type A are considered equal if and only if all their public properties are equal. One caveat: ***all decimal properties should be converted to an int before comparison, using default rounding behavior (MidpointRounding.ToEven)***. This has resulted in the following comparison code:

```
private static bool Compare(A a1, A a2)
{
    var propertiesList = typeof(A).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToList();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertiesList)
    {
        var value1 = propertyInfo.GetValue(a1);
        var value2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(a2);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
        {
            value1 = Convert.ToInt32(value1);
            value2 = Convert.ToInt32(value2);
        }

        // debugger confirms that value1 is 0 and value2 is 0
        if (value1 != value2)
        {
            // yet these lines are always called
            Console.WriteLine("The two A's are not equal");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code is intended to be written such that:

```
A1.MyProp    A2.MyProp    Equal?
---------------------------------
0.0m         0.0m         Yes
0.6m         1.4m         Yes
1.5m         2.5m         Yes
2.5m         3.5M         No
```

However, as demonstrated by the following console app, the first use case (0.0m and 0.0m) is always failing:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = new B() { MyProp = 0.0m };
    var c = new C() { MyProp = 0.0m };

    // always false
    var result = Compare(b, c);
}
```

Can anyone lend an eye and point out the bug in the comparison code?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the behavior of Convert.ToInt32(decimal); I'm doing some investigation now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `==` on `object` does reference equality.

Use `Equals` instead:

```
    // debugger confirms that value1 is 0 and value2 is 0
    if (!value1.Equals(value2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The two A's are not equal");
        return false;
    }
```

To make it null-safe you should also check for `null` first:

```
if((value1 == null && value2) != null || (value1 == null && value2 != null) || !value1.Equals(value2))
```

or as suggested in the comment use static `object.Equals`:

```
    if (!object.Equals(value1, value2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The two A's are not equal");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Better yet, use `object.Equals(value1, value2)`. I don't see anything that rules out `value1` possibly being `null`.

Comment: Ah, yup. Missed the autoboxing after the conversion. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek maybe you might want to edit the now misleading comment in the last code sample.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use Use `Equals` instead of `==` since your are dealing with objects

The Equals method is just a virtual one defined in System.Object, and overridden by whichever classes choose to do so. The == operator is an operator which can be overloaded by classes, but which usually has identity behaviour.

For reference types where == has not been overloaded, it compares whether two references refer to the same object - which is exactly what the implementation of Equals does in System.Object.

Value types do not provide an overload for == by default. However, most of the value types provided by the framework provide their own overload. The default implementation of Equals for a value type is provided by ValueType, and uses reflection to make the comparison, which makes it significantly slower than a type-specific implementation normally would be. This implementation also calls Equals on pairs of references within the two values being compared.

However, the main difference between the two types of comparison in normal use (where you're unlikely to be defining your own value types very often) is polymorphism. Operators are overloaded, not overridden, which means that unless the compiler knows to call the more specific version, it'll just call the identity version. To illustrate that, here's an example:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create two equal but distinct strings
        string a = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
        string b = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});

        Console.WriteLine (a==b);
        Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b));

        // Now let's see what happens with the same tests but
        // with variables of type object
        object c = a;
        object d = b;

        Console.WriteLine (c==d);
        Console.WriteLine (c.Equals(d));
    }
}
```

The results are:

True
True
False
True

Answer (score 0):

@MarcinJuraszek is right and he provides the exact answer has to why `!=` always returns true in your case.

I just wanted to chime in that operator overload exist and that it might make sense sometime.

Here's a sample from [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
//add this code to class ThreeDPoint as defined previously
//
public static bool operator ==(ThreeDPoint a, ThreeDPoint b)
{
    // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If one is null, but not both, return false.
    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z;
}

public static bool operator !=(ThreeDPoint a, ThreeDPoint b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```